# SQL [[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (WrapperWrite()).]General network error

Tags: sql-server, windows, vb.net

I am an Administrator for a company, we have multiple servers on premises,

1 is a Database Server (DATABASESERVER) running Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL 2008 and IIS 7
1 is a Application Server (APPSERVER) running Windows Server 2008 R2

We have a company who owns and manages our CRM System installed across all 2 of these servers, DATABASESERVER contains the Database, the HTTPSERVER contains the Internal Web CRM for the staff to use, and the APPSERVER manages the print/sms/emails/timed executions etc through the 3rd party company's applications.

The 3rd Party Company's applications keep crashing on the APPSERVER and they are blaming this on the loss of connection to the DATABASESERVER which is what an error their system is producing is saying in the logs, however the staff do not have any issues with the Website which uses the same Database.

The error message they have provided for me to fix this is at the bottom, and they are fixating on this bit of the error.

```
[[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (WrapperWrite()).]General network error. Check your network documentation.])
```

but it is my understanding that with the above section of the error there should be a SQLSTATE code?

Any help on this error would be greatly appreciated.

```
The VB Application identified by the event source logged this Application zXTmdExec: Thread ID: 12408 ,Logged: Timed execution:  zX.clsDSHPrimary.iDSHandler_sqlRS: Unable to execute query (SELECT  TOP 1 [zxPrcssMntr].[stts] AS [zxPrcssMntr_stts], [zxPrcssMntr].[autoPse] AS [zxPrcssMntr_autoPse], [zxPrcssMntr].[autoRsme] AS [zxPrcssMntr_autoRsme], [zxPrcssMntr].[lstStrtd] AS [zxPrcssMntr_lstStrtd], [zxPrcssMntr].[prcssCntrlId] AS [zxPrcssMntr_prcssCntrlId] FROM [zxPrcssMntr] WHERE (1 = 1)  AND ([zxPrcssMntr].[id] = 'timedExecGeneral') [[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (WrapperWrite()).]General network error. Check your network documentation.])
zX.clsDSHPrimary.iDSHandler_loadBO: Unable to execute load query (SELECT [zxPrcssMntr].[stts] AS [zxPrcssMntr_stts], [zxPrcssMntr].[autoPse] AS [zxPrcssMntr_autoPse], [zxPrcssMntr].[autoRsme] AS [zxPrcssMntr_autoRsme], [zxPrcssMntr].[lstStrtd] AS [zxPrcssMntr_lstStrtd], [zxPrcssMntr].[prcssCntrlId] AS [zxPrcssMntr_prcssCntrlId] FROM [zxPrcssMntr] WHERE (1 = 1)  AND ([zxPrcssMntr].[id] = 'timedExecGeneral'))
zx.clsBOS.loadBO: Error during loadBO for data source (primary)
zxMisc.clsPrcssMntr.nextCycle: Unable to reload when cycling in prcssMntr
zX.clsDSHPrimary.iDSHandler_rollbackTx: Untrapped error (Connection failure)
zXTmdExec.modMain.goGoGo: Severe process monitor error
zX.clsDSHPrimary.iDSHandler_sqlExecute: Unable to execute query (DELETE FROM [zxSssn] WHERE (1 = 1)  AND ([zxSssn].[id] = 79495)[[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (WrapperWrite()).]General network error. Check your    network documentation.])
zX.clsDSHPrimary.iDSHandler_deleteBO: Unable to delete BO
zx.clsBOS.deleteBO: Delete by data-source handler failed (primary)
zx.clsSession.disConnect: Unable to delete session
```

Comment: This error means the network connection on the AppServer went completely offline. Database server + IIS app there was still available to your employees, but AppServer network interface was down.

Comment: Thanks for the response Joel, I have a Zabbix monitoring platform onsite which doesn't show any loss of connection for the monitoring,

we have replaced the network card, and replaced the switch thinking this was the case, but it doesn't seem to be.